# Why URLconf is working locally but failing in production

Tags: python, django, apache, urlconf

I am just setting up an empty django project to test a new server.   I have my django project working locally, showing the "Hello World!" for for the base URL and also and data/ app domain.

main_project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^data/', include('data.urls'), name="data"),
    url(r'^', include('mainsite.urls'), name="mainsite"),
]
```

main_project/mainsite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'mainsite'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

main_project/data/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'data'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Its a very basic setup, and locally, using `python manage.py runserver` everything works.

One production the base url (http://www.mondonect.com/) works but the data url (http://www.mondonect.com/data) fails with the following error:

[image]

Strange that it works locally but not in production.

Its apache 2 server with wsgi, ubuntu 14.04.  Django version 1.10.2.

Comment: Does it work when you append a backslash `data/`? And your `include` should use namespaces not names.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye it does not work on production with `data/` but yes it does work like that on local.  I haven't used the namespaces in URLconf before so I will have to read about that.

Comment: You really shouldn't run production with `settings.DEBUG`. Also, could it be that you first pushed a version without this url, then push the new version and didn't restart your wsgi process ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - Thanks for the advice, I understand about the Debug setting.  I am really just testing out this new server.  It is the first time I am using this server configuration.  I was just pushing up an empty project as a "hello world" to make sure it works.  I was just about done, seeing how the base url site worked.  I have been using `service apache2 reload` to restart the server.  I just checked it again right now and it appears to be working now...